# Incorrect output when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am doing gradient descent (100 iterations to be precise). Each data point can be analyzed in parallel, there are 50 data points. Since I have 4 cores, I create a pool of 4 workers using `multiprocessing.Pool`. The core of the program looks like following:

```
# Read the sgf files (total 50)
(intermediateBoards, finalizedBoards) = read_sgf_files()

# Create a pool of processes to analyze game boards in parallel with as 
# many processes as number of cores
pool =  Pool(processes=cpu_count())

# Initialize the parameter object
param = Param()

# maxItr = 100 iterations of gradient descent
for itr in range(maxItr):
    args = []
    # Prepare argument vector for each file
    for i in range(len(intermediateBoards)):
        args.append((intermediateBoards[i], finalizedBoards[i], param))
    # 4 processes analyze 50 data points in parallel in each iteration of 
    # gradient descent
    result = pool.map_async(train_go_crf_mcmc, args)
```

Now, I haven't included definition for the function `train_go_crf`, but the very first line in the function is a print statement. So, when I execute this function the print statement should get executed 100*50 times. But that does not happen. What's more, I get different number of console outputs different number of times.

What's wrong?

Comment: suspect your issue is `map_ascync` is non-blocking.  Does it work correctly if you use `map` instead?

Comment: @tcaswell: I think you are correct. Then adding a simple sleep() function that suspends the main process for few seconds while all the asynchronous calls finish their execution should work, right?

Comment: Are you calling `get` on the `AsyncResult` object in a line of code you aren't showing?

Comment: @Jared: I haven't written that piece of code, but yes, I'll call `get` on the `AsyncResult` object. I guess that would wait for all the asynchronous call to finish, right?

Comment: @Jared: I guess the iterable object returned by `map_async` wouldn't wait till all the calls are finished (if say there are 1 million calls) but would start populating the iterable object as calls finish their execution.

Comment: To fix this I think you just need to do `result.get()` and save it in some way before you move onto the next iteration see http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `map_async` instead of `map`.  This means that once all of the work is farmed out to the pool, it will continue on with the loop, even if all of the work has not been finished.  It is not clear to me what will happen to the work still running when the next loop starts, but if these are supposed to be iterations, I can't imagine it is a) good b) well defined.

If you use `map`, it will block the loop until *all* of the worker functions have finished before moving on to the next step.  I guess you could do this with `sleep`, but that would just make things more complicated for no gain.  `map` will wait for *exactly* the minimum  amount of time it needs to to let everything finish.